# How to compute the significant difference in two dataset in R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, hypothesis-test, significance

I have two numeric vectors each shows the days we need to do different tasks: a using new technology versus in b using a old technology

> a <- c(10, 59, 30, 5)
>
> b<- c(19, 70, 50, 25)

I need to know is there a significant difference between a and b? and if yes estimate the Magnitude of Differences Between Two Groups?

Answer (score 0):

if your values are normally distributed, you can use R's inbuilt `t.test` function. If not you can use the `wilcox.test` function (no assumption about how the population is distributed).

The magnitude of difference you can probably just calculate as a fold change.

```
t.test(a,b)
wilcox.test(a,b)

foldChange = mean(a)/mean(b)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, do you think Paired  t test is appropriate in my example?

Comment: a paired t test would apply if the individual values from a and b are connected in some way, so e.g. the first value of a and b each come from the same specimen, the second value of a and b come from another specimen and so on

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both of the sample groups a and b come from normal distributions, you can define and test if there is a significant difference in the means of both groups with a two sample t-test as follows.

Note, it would help to know if the variance of the two populations are equal or not, but this is also addressed in the t.test function's arguments:

t.test(a, b, alternative="two.sided", var.equal=FALSE, conf.level=0.95)